# Font problems on retina display

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uicolor, uifont, drawinrect

I'm kind of newbie in Objective-C and I need some help
My problem is that I have a subclass of `UITextField`, and I want to set the placeholder font to be custom with this code

```
- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
[[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia Belle" size:25],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:RGBA(174, 150, 108, 1)}]; }
```

and I have the next issue.
When I select iPad in the simulator, and I compile the program, everything goes as it should, but when I select a retina device I get the next Exception:

```
 [__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0].
```

What I'm asking is: why it works on non-retina but throws exceptions on retina, any kind of retina device.

Comment: I would split your method into single chunks. First get the font in a variable, the the color, and then call the method. Now you can step-by-step debug the code and see why you probably get no font object.

Comment: i've tried, but it still happens

Comment: What did your debugger told you. Did you actually got a NSFont object?

Comment: As suggested by @Flovdis, I'd log each values of the attributes dictionary.

Comment: yes, i've got, but that's obvious, because otherwise it would not work on non-retina device, as i said: On Non-retina device it's working.

Comment: Why are you subclassing `UITextField` for this? Just use the `attributedPlaceholder` property of `UITextField`.

Comment: You should not assume the fonts available are the same on both classes of device and ignore the suggestions to approach this step-by-step. Breaking problems down is how we solve them.

Comment: when i split it, and i NSLog the font, this is what i've got. <UICTFont: 0x10a10cff0> font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt.
it make-s no sense.

Comment: I hope my answer can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with your Font.

`HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular` is the System font. Like: `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]`

In the other hand I can't use `RGBA(174, 150, 108, 1)` I've got an issue in my code.

You should be sure that you have the font named **"Georgia Belle"** is in your project well imported.

Drag and drop **Georgia Belle.ttf** to your project

[image]

Open Info.plist and add a new line:

[image]

Open your Target / Build Phases / Copy Bundle Resources
Xcode fails here and sometimes its not adding our new font:

[image]

Click +

[image]

Done

[image]

Problem solved.

[image]
[image]

You can [download my solution from GitHub](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/Custom_Placeholder_UITextField)

One last thing. This is a nice website with all the standard ios fonts: http://iosfonts.com

Comment: you can't use RGBA(r,g,b,alpha) because it's a macro i'm using for color with RGBA.

Comment: it worked, the only think i haven't done,was, adding the font in my "copy bundle resources", but i can't figure out, why it worked on non-retina device

Comment: Nice! I neither can't understand the difference between Retina and non-Retina. In my code wasn't working in both.

Comment: i have another question based on this:
One of my co-workers told me that, it's not ok to call the drawInRect method, is there any other way to change the placeholder style, without calling this method, and why it's not ok?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the font to the copy bundle resources